# Replace $_POST send by ajax with another $_POST

Tags: php, json, ajax, post

How to replace data send with AJAX?! i would like to send changing value.

html:

```
<div id="next"><button><span>Next</span></button></div>
```

part of jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
  val = 0;
  $.getJSON("question.json", function(response) {
    json = response;
    populate(json.geometry[val]);

  });

  $("#next").on('click', function(event) {
    $("#quiz").fadeOut("slow", function() {
      jsonsize = json.geometry.length
      if (val < jsonsize) {
        val = val + 1;
      }
      populate(json.geomatry[val]);

    });
  });
});
```

ajax call:

```
$("#result").click(function() {
  $(".progress").show();
  post_data = {
    $questionid: val
  };
  $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    data_Type: 'text',
    data: post_data,
    url: 'count.php',
    success: function(data) {
      result = data;
      alert(result)
    }
  });
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$val = $_POST['$questionid']; 
$jsonString = file_get_contents('question.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);


echo $val;
unset($val);
$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('question.json', $newJsonString);
?>
```

As you see my php code work with json data. My PHP code replace json data(that part of my code work correctly), that't why i did not gives that information to let the code be more clearly, visible .
In that type of code when user click check -> question id is send to php -> PHP do the job   but... like in example. on 1st question php alert will be "0"
on 2nd queston alert will be "1" and next aler "1". So when user will be on 20th question alert will be called 20 times.

Already try unset("") but without a effect. any idea?!

Comment: what do you see in your inspector network tab when you execute ? php does not "alert" you may need to add some var_dumps or echos to see if PHP is doing what you expect

Comment: com one.. php code gives echo $val;  using ajax i call echo as a alert, becouse php working on background without page refresh.

Comment: and as i said. PHP doing the job, but when value increase doing job too many times :D

Comment: evertime you run this php code i am assuming this is from a client side event (click or other) the $var is set at that time based on the $_POST. to me it looks like you are reading a file and writing the exact same contentsr back to that file. am i  missing something? what do you want to happen?

Comment: val increase by 1 every time user click next.  everything working without refresh. so when user start php execute code 1, but when user click next php execute code twice when should one..

Comment: We might need to see a little more maybe some markup so we can see what is triggering your ajax

Comment: added part of my jQuery.

Comment: i cannot see your html markup but if #next is a submit button or an a tag you might need a `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: I am still not understanding what you want to change. Teh javascript variable or the php one? are there some important pieces of your pp code missing?

Comment: my php is on diffrent file, so my button is just a button without submit.(for submit effect i using ajax call)  so i'm not going to different url.

Comment: I understand that you do not want a page refresh and that is why the AJAX is used.I still don't understand your question. Can you rephrase your question please. tell us what you want to happen and what is happening now

Comment: i need to change PHP code. becouse php stores the value from POST method.   value from js sending ones to php keeps inside php. As i said. if i refresh and start from question 15,  i have a alert with number 15, when click next i have 2 alerts, so to restart that i need to refresh, with i dont wont. Only thing i can do is delate $val after execute and send it again with ajax or replace exisiting $val when sending, but i dont know how to do it... thats why i try unset...

Comment: Ah i think i understand you now. What you may need to do is use a [`$_session`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). Since php is a server-side tech and javascript is a client-side the php variables are "baked" once you see them in the browser.

Comment: i used session_start on beginning of my php code and on the end try both session_unset();  and session_destroy();   but still same issue...

Comment: there is a solution? how to do that without refresh?? because i cant refresh page...

Comment: `data_Type:` should be `dataType:`

Comment: Is your AJAX call inside the first `$(function() { ... })`? The variable `val` is local to that function, so you can't access it in the click handler if it's outside.

Comment: You also have another typo: `json.geomatry` should be `json.geometry`.

Comment: Instead of unsetting your session just chage the session val you want. for example `$_SESSION['my_variable'] = 15;` // or whatever value you need it to have at that moment which could also be set to the $_POST data (more likely how you will do it)